# Is my credit card page secure? Safeguard inquiry

Tags: security, logic, checkout

https: xyz dot com/authenticate/cc.php

This is the page 3 of my registration....where my members enter their credit card. This is tied into my authorize.net account.

One thing i noticed recently is this page can be accessed on its own just by typing in the URL.. there is no required pre-url that leads up to it. This seems unsafe, but regardless if someone wanted to abuse it they could just go through the registration process and keep submitting incorrect CC numbers.. costing me money right?

I dont remember if we put an IP limit on it, or again if that is even 100% safeguard. 
I am pretty sure we did something where if they enter mastercard with their number(temporarily stored) and it gets sent back as invalid it will match that and not allow them to keep entering the wrong 16 digit number.
Should i just leave the page accessible without specific pages allowing access and worrying about IP limits instead? Couldn't someone just keep switching their ip and submitting this page with incorrect CC's or fake ones at that?

What is the proper way to secure this page considering i/losing my merchant account could be the one at risk?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you pay for declined transactions? That seems odd, payment gateways only usually charge for authorisations that succeed.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you would allow direct acces to the 3rd step of the process, where is all the other data like the user name, addres, ...?

This are some ideas of what I would do, a completely secure system (which might not exists) would be much more complex than my simple steps.

**note** that you probably would like to first allow the users to register with some information where you can *know* who they are (verified email, verified phone number, etc) then and only then, you do the credit card thing, and if they continuosly input wrong or invalid numbers, you can do something else, like black-listing them, call them, insult them, etc..

**note 2** I spent long time writting this, the more I read it and think about it, the worse it seems to be, but as it is already written I'll post it anyway.

Some notes before begin:

- There is only one address, for example /authenticate/auth.php
- The process has a "state" and depending on this, it will show/do different things.
- For different states has other extra files which are *included* depending on the state.
- After the process starts, a session is created and linked with the user IP, the process state and any other identifiable information about the user, for example 'User-Agent', this data is saved in the server.
- Seems you would like to show a different state using different pages, so it will be like that. But actually I would do in a single page using ajax calls.
- There is **NO** black-listing of suspicious IP addresses(too many normal or buggy or completely wrong requests), it could be added if desired, but the complexity increases. You might or might not want to do this, maybe a capcha would be enough, but..
- There is **NO** capcha which might help in some cases, but the session handling I describe here might need to change.
- There is **NO** email verification which you probably want to do.

Let's say that the process states are ask_name, ask_address, ask_cc, etc...

So, when there is any request to the auth page (/authenticate/auth.php), this is what we could do:

> 1 If 'Referer' doesn't come from one of the possible process starters (main page, etc,) or this page (/authenticate/auth.php), we *redirect* to the main page. **end**.

This first step avoids people writting the address directly or coming from untrusted pages.

> 2 If there is no session information for this request:
>
> 2.1 If there is a 'user_name' parameter AND 'Referer' is this page (/authenticate/auth.php)
>
> 2.1.1 If that user name is already registered, show(include, not redirect) 'ask_name.php' with the extra notice "User already registered". **end**.
>
> 2.1.2 Create a session for this user, link it with it's IP, User Agent, etc, other data.
>
> 2.1.3 Set the state to ask_address (the second) and show 'ask_address.php'. **end**.
>
> 2.2 Else (no parameter or 'Referer' was wrong)
>
> 2.2.1 Show 'ask_name.php'. **end**.

This second step either shows the first screen (ask_user) or the second (ask_name), it delays the creation of the session until we are sure the user wants to do something real.

It has a couple of problems:

- Some user (or program) continuosly sends requests without session but with 'user_name', so forcing you to always check if the user is valid or not, and may slow things down. This could be avoided using several different techniquest, for example using a capcha or by black listing some IPs for some time.
- It could be possible that one user start the process with a 'user_name' which doesn't exists, but he is slow and takes some time to finish the process, while this is happening, a second user begins and finish the process with the same 'user_name', so when the first user is going to finish, it will fail at the last step. This could be avoided with several different techniques which are left as an exercice.

> 3 If there is session information for this requests (this is the *else* to the previous step)
>
> 3.1 If referer is not this page OR the IP stored in the server is not the same as the current request OR some other data like User Agent is different OR the state is invalid (not in the list of states), remove the session id from the request (so the browser deletes it) and show 'ask_name.php' with the extra notice "Looks like your device changed!!!". **end**.
>
> 3.2 'include' the page for the *state*:
>
> 3.2.1 If the parameters are passed and are correct, set the state to *the-next-state* and show the page for it. If is the last state do something appropiate for the last state. **end**.
>
> 3.2.2 Show the same page for this state with an error message for the user to retry. **end**.

This last step tries to ensure that the request is not coming from a different computer and/or with stolen session keys.